# How to read bytes as bytes from csv?

Tags: python, csv, io, byte, type-conversion

I have a csv with ~10 columns.. One of the columns has information in bytes i.e., `b'gAAAA234'`. But when I read this from pandas via `.read_csv("file.csv")`, I get it all in a dataframe and this particular column is in string rather than bytes i.e., `b'gAAAA234'`.

How do I simply read it as bytes without having to read it as string and then reconverting?

Currently, I'm working with this:

```
    b = df['column_with_data_in_bytes'][i]
    bb = bytes(b[2:len(b)-1],'utf-8')
    #further processing of bytes
```

This works but I was hoping to find a more elegant/pythonic or more reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider parsing with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
df['column_with_data_in_bytes'] = df['column_with_data_in_bytes'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Demo:

```
In [322]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Col' : ["b'asdfghj'", "b'ssdgdfgfv'", "b'asdsfg'"]})

In [325]: df
Out[325]: 
            Col
0    b'asdfghj'
1  b'ssdgdfgfv'
2     b'asdsfg'

In [326]: df.Col.apply(ast.literal_eval)
Out[326]: 
0      asdfghj
1    ssdgdfgfv
2       asdsfg
Name: Col, dtype: object
```